# How to calculate the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\sin(2\phi x)-2\phi x)\cot(\phi x)\csc^2(\phi x)$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

How to calculate the limit?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\sin(2\phi x)-2\phi x)\cot(\phi x)\csc^2(\phi x)=-\frac{4}{3}$$

where $\displaystyle \phi$ is a real number.

Comment: I tried L'Hospital rule, but i don't have success!

Comment: Did you mean to say $\sin$?

Comment: @SimpleArt I believe $\operatorname{sen}$ is the Spanish for $\sin$

Answer (score 0):

First see that

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\mathcal O(x^5)$$

So,

$$\sin(2\phi x)-2\phi x=\color{#4488dd}{-\frac43}\phi^3x^3+\mathcal O(x^5)$$

Similarly,

$$\cot(\phi x)\csc^2(\phi x)=\frac{\cos(\phi x)}{\sin^3(\phi x)}=\frac{\cos(\phi x)}{\phi^3x^3-2\phi^5x^5+\mathcal O(x^7)}$$

And combining all of this,

$$\begin{align}(\sin(2\phi x)-2\phi x)\cot(\phi x)\csc^2(\phi x)&=\frac{\cos(\phi x)(-\frac43\phi^3x^3+\mathcal O(x^5))}{\phi^3x^3-2\phi^5x^5+\mathcal O(x^7)}\\&=\frac{\cos(\phi x)(-\frac43+\mathcal O(x^2))}{1-2\phi^2x^2+\mathcal O(x^5)}\\&\to\color{#4488dd}{-\frac43}\end{align}$$